# Android - Display URLs in Webview from List with Different Times one after each other

Tags: android, webview, timer, handler

I have a List and I need to Display all websites from this list in a Loop one after each other in a WebView. Between switching from one website to the other one I have also a individual time which is also in a other list with the same size.

But if I try to display the site in a WebView it sometimes skips a website and the times are not accurate. Can someone improve my code please and tell me where the misstake is?

```
public class WebshowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<String> htmlSites = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Integer> timeForSite = new ArrayList<>();
private int counter = 0;
WebView webView;
boolean firstCall = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webshow);
    //Fullscreen settings
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    //implement list from utils
    timeForSite.add(10);//this is the 0th index and it's needed for the first URL load which is emepty
    for (int i = 0; i < Utilities.list.size(); i++) {
        htmlSites.add(Utilities.list.get(i).getPath());
        timeForSite.add(Utilities.list.get(i).getDuration());
    }
    //WebView
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Toast.makeText(WebshowActivity.this, "Time for this Website: " + timeForSite.get(counter) + "ms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    webView.loadUrl(htmlSites.get(counter));
                    counter++;
                    if (firstCall == true) {
                        timeForSite.remove(0);
                        firstCall = false;
                    } else {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if (counter == htmlSites.size()) {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }
            }, timeForSite.get(counter));
        }
    });
}
```

}

The Lists are in a other Class but I think the error is inside the onPageFinished Method.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: To make scheduling more precise using Timer.

Here is an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //mock
    private static class SomeComplicatedObject {
        private final String mPath;
        private final Integer mDuration;

        public SomeComplicatedObject(final String path, final int duration){
            mPath = path;
            mDuration = duration;
        }

        String getPath() { return mPath; }
        Integer getDureation() { return mDuration;    }
    }

    private static final List<SomeComplicatedObject> complicatedList = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        complicatedList.add(new SomeComplicatedObject("http://google.com", 1000));
        complicatedList.add(new SomeComplicatedObject("http://facebook.com", 2000));
        complicatedList.add(new SomeComplicatedObject("http://google.com", 3000));
        complicatedList.add(new SomeComplicatedObject("http://twitter.com", 3000));
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private final ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> mSitesToDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Timer mTimer = new Timer("LoadNext");
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private WebView mWebView = null;
    private int mIndex = -1;

    private void fillSitesToDisplay(List<SomeComplicatedObject> list) {
        mIndex = -1;
        mSitesToDisplay.clear();
        for (SomeComplicatedObject item : list) {
            mSitesToDisplay.add(new Pair<>(item.getPath(), item.getDureation()));
        }
    }

    private Pair<String, Integer> getNext() {
        mIndex = (mIndex+1) % mSitesToDisplay.size();
        return mSitesToDisplay.get(mIndex);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fillSitesToDisplay(complicatedList);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        //initial start delayed by 1 sec
        mTimer.schedule(createTimerTask(), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
    }

    private Runnable mDisplayNextPage = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Pair<String, Integer> pathTimePair = getNext();
            Log.e(TAG, "DisplayNext::run :  Start loading next page : " + pathTimePair.first);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WaitPageLoadedClient(mTimer, createTimerTask(), pathTimePair.second));
            mWebView.loadUrl(pathTimePair.first);
        }
    };

    private TimerTask createTimerTask() {
        return new TimerTriggered(mHandler, mDisplayNextPage);
    }

    //simple utility class for notifying timer triggered event
    //on UI thread.
    private static class TimerTriggered extends TimerTask {
        Runnable mOnTriggered;
        Handler mHandler;

        protected TimerTriggered(Handler handler, Runnable onTriggered) {
            super();
            mHandler = handler;
            mOnTriggered = onTriggered;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Timer runs int it's own thread so we need to
            //pass execution to MainThread for accessing WebView.
            mHandler.post(mOnTriggered);
        }
    }

    private static class WaitPageLoadedClient extends WebViewClient {
        private final TimerTask mRunOnFinished;
        private final Timer mTimer;
        private final Integer mDelay;

        public WaitPageLoadedClient(Timer timer, TimerTask toRunOnFinished, Integer delay) {
            mRunOnFinished = toRunOnFinished;
            mTimer = timer;
            mDelay = delay;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onPageFinished: Schedule timer for " + mDelay);
            mTimer.schedule(mRunOnFinished, mDelay);
        }
    }
}
```

It will cycle forever.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working fine but I have only a problem with the time. It's not always constant.

Comment: Than you need to use Timer or CountDownTimer instead of handler. Because handler relly on UI thread and not garanted to be presice

Comment: @htlstudent I've updated answer by using Timer instead. It should be more precise now.